# How to copy the value from one input box to another input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By clicking on Add New Row button, new input boxes can be generated. I want to copy the value from one input box (First column - Hours ) to another input box (Second Column - In Office).

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**First Row:** Value is copied from one input box to another input box when it is a static element. Here input box is created by HTML.

**Dynamic Rows:** Value is not copied from one input box to another input box when it is a dynamic element. Here input box is created by JavaScript.

**Issue:**

Value is not copied because the elements are generated dynamically with same `id` and `name`

**What I tried:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
  // Append table with add row form on add new button click
  $(".add_new").click(function() {
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var row = '<tr>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="hours[]" id="hours"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" id="inoffice"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
  // Add row on add button click
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    var empty = false;
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
    input.each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        empty = true;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
    if (!empty) {
      input.each(function() {
        $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
      });
    }
  });
});

function sync() {
  var hours = document.getElementById('hours');
  var inoffice = document.getElementById('inoffice');
  inoffice.value = hours.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>In Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" name="hours[]" id="hours" onkeyup="sync()" onClick="sync()"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" id="inoffice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="add_new" name="add_new" class="add_new" value="Add New Row">
```

Comment: Elements cannot share an ID (otherwise it's not an ID). Start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be duplicating `id` attributes as it's invalid HTML and will lead to other issues. Use `class` attributes instead to group elements by common behaviour patterns.

From there you can use a delegated event handler to handle all the `.hours` elements that will ever exist in the DOM.

Also note that inline event attributes are outdated and should be avoided where possible.

```
$('table').on('input', '.hours', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.inoffice').val(this.value);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
  
  $(".add_new").click(function() {
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var row = '<tr>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="hours[]" class="hours"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" class="inoffice"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", ".add", function() {
    var empty = false;
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
    input.each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        $(this).addClass("error");
        empty = true;
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
    if (!empty) {
      input.each(function() {
        $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
      });
    }
  });
  
  $('table').on('input', '.hours', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.inoffice').val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>In Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" name="hours[]" class="hours"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" class="inoffice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="add_new" name="add_new" class="add_new" value="Add New Row">
```

Answer (score 0):

- Start by creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That means remove all the code that isn't part of the problem. This will make everything clearer.
- Remove IDs, since IDs must be unique, we better use classes instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(".add_new").click(function() {
    var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
    var row = '<tr>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="hours[]" class="hours"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" class="inoffice"></td>' +
      '</tr>';
    $("table").append(row);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
  
});

$(document).on("keyup", ".hours", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".inoffice").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>In Office</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" name="hours[]" class="hours"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="inoffice[]" class="inoffice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="add_new" name="add_new" class="add_new" value="Add New Row">
```